# SQL Server: Sum and inner join

Tags: sql-server, sum, inner-join

I have two tables:

- `DepotSessions`: `ID (int), Date (date), StartTime (int), EndTime (int), TruckID (int)`
- `DepotSessionDetails`: `ID (int), DepotSessionID (int), Status (varchar(20)), Duration (int)`

I need to know how many times each truck was loaded (`TotalLoadCount`), how long it was loaded (`TotalLoadTime`) and how much time it spent in the depot (`TotalDepotTime`).

There can be multiple `DepotSessionRows` for a given `TruckID` and `Date`. Also, there can be multiple `DepotSessionDetails` rows for a given `DepotSessionID`.

Some sample data:

**DepotSessions**:

```
ID  TruckID  Date           StartTime   EndTime
-----------------------------------------------
1      1     '2013-04-01'      500        3000
2      1     '2013-04-01'    14000       25000
```

**DepotSessionDetails**:

```
ID    DepotSessionID   Status    Duration
------------------------------------------
1          1           'Waiting'    40
2          1           'Loading'    25
3          1           'Waiting'    33
4          1           'Loading'    38
5          2           'Waiting'    100
6          2           'Loading'    167
7          2           'Waiting'    420
8          2           'Loading'    980
```

Based on this sample data, I need to get:

- `TotalDepotTime` 13500 (as in 25000 - 14000 + 3000 - 500)
- `TotalLoadTime` 1210
- `TotalLoadCount` 4

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
SELECT 
    DS.Date, DS.TruckID, 
    MIN(DS.StartTime), MAX(DS.EndTime),
    SUM(DS.EndTime-DS.StartTime) TotalDepotTime,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DSD.Status = 'Loading' THEN DSD.Duration ELSE 0 END) TotalLoadTime,
    COUNT(CASE DSD.Status = 'Loading' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalLoadCount
FROM 
    DepotSessions DS
INNER JOIN 
    DepotSessionDetails DSD  on DS.ID = DSD.DepotSessionID
GROUP BY 
    Date, TruckID
```

- `TotalDepotTime` 54000 (incorrect, should be 13500)
- `TotalLoadTime` 1210
- `TotalLoadCount` 8 (incorrect, should be 4)

Comment: Can you post some sample data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DS.Date, DS.TruckID, 
       MIN(DS.StartTime), MAX(DS.EndTime),
       sum(distinct(DS.EndTime))-sum(distinct(DS.StartTime)) as TotalDepotTime,
       SUM( CASE DSD.Status WHEN 'Loading' THEN DSD.Duration ELSE 0 END) TotalLoadTime,
       SUM(CASE DSD.Status WHEN 'Loading' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalLoadCount
FROM DepotSessions DS
INNER JOIN DepotSessionDetails DSD  on DS.ID = DSD.DepotSessionID
GROUP BY TruckID, date;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d425/24)

Comment: The TotalDepotTime is now 432000. It should be 13500.

Answer (score 0):

> divided by the number of DepotSessions rows for that Date and TruckID.

Above line is  not clear .
you can try this way,

```
select 
    *, TotalDepotTime * TotalLoadCount 
from 
    (SELECT 
         DS.Date, DS.TruckID, MIN(DS.StartTime), MAX(DS.EndTime),
         SUM(DS.EndTime-DS.StartTime) TotalDepotTime,
         SUM(CASE DSD.Status WHEN 'Loading' THEN DSD.Duration ELSE 0 END) TotalLoadTime,
         COUNT(CASE DSD.Status WHEN 'Loading' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalLoadCount
     FROM 
         DepotSessions DS
     INNER JOIN 
         DepotSessionDetails DSD ON DS.ID = DSD.DepotSessionID
     GROUP BY Date, TruckID) tbl
```

Comment: `starttime` and `endtime` are int so why do you need datediff??

Comment: oh sorry.you can check now and also clear my doubts .